# How can I create a download link to send via Plivo using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vcf-vcard, plivo

So I have a `vCard file`, and I want to send a link to a user via sms through `Plivo` that allows them to click on a link to download the `vCard`. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use something like [Ge.tt](http://ge.tt/developers/rest) to post the vCard file and you'll get a public url back. Then use [this Plivo tutorial](https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/send-a-single-sms/) to send an SMS with the link to the user's phone number.